# How to use sliders in clojure seesaw

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I'm new to clojure (and even newer to seesaw) but have a lot of Java experience and a fair amount of swing experience.

I'm trying to create a window with some drop-down text boxes and a slider on it. However, I'm having trouble getting all the pieces to be displayed on one window (rather than one at a time) and for some reason the slider isn't being displayed.

I cannot really find a lot of tutorials on this, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

```
    (defn window [cuisine-input rating-input location-slider]
        (seesaw/frame
        :title "Resturant Selector"
        :content (cuisine-input rating-input location-slider)
        :width 200
        :height 50
        :on-close :exit))


    (defn -main
    [& args]

        (def cuisine (seesaw/input "Please choose a type of cuisine: "
                           :choices ["Indian" "Japanese" "Chinese"
                                     "Burgers"]))

        (def rating (seesaw/input "Please choose the ideal rating: "
                        :choices ["1 star" "2 stars" "3 stars" "4 stars" 
                                  "5 stars"]))
        (def location (seesaw/slider 
                             :value 5 :min 0 :max 20 
                             :minor-tick-spacing 1 :major-tick-spacing 2 
                             :snap-to-ticks? true 
                             :paint-ticks? true :paint-labels? true))

        (def main-window (window cuisine rating location))
        (seesaw/pack! (window main-window))
        (seesaw/show! (window main-window))
```

)

I've also tried something like this:

```
    (seesaw/frame :title "Resturant Selector" :on-close :exit
            :content (:items [ 
                     (seesaw/input "Please choose a type of cuisine: "
                           :choices ["Indian" "Japanese" "Chinese"
                                    "Burgers"])

                     (seesaw/input "Please choose the ideal rating: "
                        :choices ["1 star" "2 stars" "3 stars" "4 stars" 
                                  "5 stars"])

                     (seesaw/slider
                       :value 5 :min 0 :max 20
                       :minor-tick-spacing 1 :major-tick-spacing 2
                       :snap-to-ticks? true
                       :paint-ticks? true :paint-labels? true)]
                              )
            )
```

Comment: I don't know Seesaw, but I notice that the git repo hasn't been updated since Clojure 1.4.0.  If you're using a later version of Clojure, I wonder whether that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Try changing the `(seesaw/pack! (window main-window))
        (seesaw/show! (window main-window))` to `(seesaw/pack! main-window)
        (seesaw/show! main-window)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[seesaw/input](https://daveray.github.io/seesaw/seesaw.core-api.html#seesaw.core/input) creates an [input dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), while you want to create a [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). The [wiki](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/wiki/Widgets) has a nice help about how to create widgets and you can find a list of available widgets in the [API doc](https://daveray.github.io/seesaw/seesaw.core-api.html).

To have more than one widget in [a frame](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/wiki/Frames) you need [a container](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/wiki/Containers).

So for your particular example, you will need something similar to:

```
(defn window [content]
  (seesaw/frame
    :title "Resturant Selector"
    :content content
    :width 200
    :height 50
    :on-close :close))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [rating-label (seesaw/label :text "Please choose rating:")
        rating (seesaw/combobox :model ["1 star" "2 star"])
        location (seesaw/slider
                   :value 5 :min 0 :max 20
                   :minor-tick-spacing 1 :major-tick-spacing 2
                   :snap-to-ticks? true
                   :paint-ticks? true :paint-labels? true)

        main-window (window (seesaw/vertical-panel :items [rating-label rating location]))]
    (seesaw/invoke-later
      (seesaw/pack! main-window)
      (seesaw/show! main-window))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @LucasRudd consider placing a green checkmark next to this answer then. Cheers!